# Metafont (or alternative ways to get your own scripts within LaTeX)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, metafont

My main experience with Metafont was Christopher Grandsire's [The METAFONTtutorial](http://metafont.tutorial.free.fr/downloads/mftut.pdf) which I think is a good and concise description of the language and its tricks, but I've missing one important part:
how to produce a .PDF or printed document using your newly created font.

So.  **How can I write a *Hello World* document using a newly created font with Metafont?**  (Or with any other font I would've created by a package such as Fontographer, FontForge, etc.)

Comment: I believe this is as simple as \font\myfont=mymetafont.mf \myfont This is my meta font \vfill\eject\bye when mymetafont.mf is in the working directory, or the font paths searched by TeX.

Comment: @WillAdams  Running my `tex hello.tex` example I get a .dvi which I cannot read in my dvi reader.  `dvips` produces the same result, and `ps2pdf` does not show the commanded characters.  `pdftex` reports error _“!pdfTeX error: pdftex (file chlscr): Font chlscr at 600 not found”_ and `luatex` reports _“! Font \myfont=chlscr.mf not loadable: metric data not found or bad.”_  I might be missing some step.

Comment: I think this may then be addressed by the FAQ: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=useMF

Comment: Found the problem: I failed to create the metric file with the `gftomk` command.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón I think you mean the `gftopk` command, which creates a `.pk` file. Metafont itself creates the metric file (exension `.tfm`). The error you quote from pdftex indicate a missing file named `chlscr.600pk`. On the other hand the error from luatex indicates a missing .tfm file. That could come from using the incorrect `\font` command. It should be `\font\myfont=chlscr` (without extension), not `\font\myfont=chlscr.mf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is a working example using LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newfont{\myscr}{chlscr}
\begin{document}
This is a {\myscr hello world} example:

{\myscr
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
}
\end{document}
```

And this is a working example using plain TeX, as suggested by [WillAdams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31151/willadams):

```
\font\myfont=chlscr.mf Hello: \myfont hello world \vfill\eject\bye
```

For these examples to work, I need to run
`mf '\mode=ljfour; input chlscr.mf'` *to create the* chlscr.600gf *and* chlscr.tmf *files*.
`gftopk chlscr.600gf chlscr.600pk` *to create the* chlscr.600pk *file.*

Without this metric files `pdftex` and `pdflatex` will fail.  (and `tex` and `latex` commands will compile but the generated .dvi won't work.)