# No spaces in a font created with Metafont

Tags: fonts, spacing, metafont

Finally I got my font created with Metafont, to appear on a PDF using LaTeX.  Using [the example in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142706/36281).

[image: Hello World]

The problem is that I have no space between words.  How can I get spacing between words?  I understand that this should be some parameter in either the `.mf` or the `.tfm` file.

My metafont source is located in [GitHub](https://github.com/chlewey/chlewtex/blob/master/fonts/chlscr.mf) (too long to past it here).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a font to be usable it has to have certain dimension parameters set. The TeXbook calls these font dimensions and the size of a space is one, as are the stretchability and shrinkability of the space. MF has commands to set these. There are others and, at a minimum you should set these 7 (I've given sample values to illustrate the syntax):

```
font_size 10pt#;
font_slant 0; % number of points moved rightward per point moved upward
font_normal_space 3.5pt#;
font_normal_stretch 2pt#;
font_normal_shrink 1.5pt#;
font_x_height 4.5pt#;
font_quad 10pt#;
```

These are actually commands, not parameters. They read the following number and set the appropriate font dimension. These can be pure numbers (interpreted as points) or sharped units. These commands can apparently be issued at any time.

Caveat: The only experience I've had with these is in experiments I've conducted with changing them in existing fonts.