# How to add space character in Computer Modern font

Tags: metafont, computer-modern

I am using METAFONT sources of Knuth’s `cmr7.mf` Com­puter Modern font. For converting this file into outline font, I have used mftrace. Everything works fine when i convert this `.mf` file into `.TTF` file but when i view this file in a font viewer i see a polish l-slash character, instead of space character.

I have tried adding these commands in it still there is no difference

```
font_identifier:="CMR";
font_size 7pt#;
font_normal_space 3.5pt#;
font_normal_stretch 2pt#;
font_normal_shrink 1.5pt#;
font_x_height 4.5pt#;
font_quad 10pt#;
```

Comment: By design, there's no use for a “space character” in TeX. So the fonts can use the slot for other purposes.

Comment: @egreg by this reference https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142708/no-spaces-in-a-font-created-with-metafont i think there is a possibility that we can add space characters using specific commands? Am i right?

Comment: A font has some parameters that tell TeX how much space to leave between words typeset with that font. The glyph in slot 32 of the font is *never* used for such spaces. You can type `\symbol{32}` and this will print the glyph in slot 32 of the current font, which may or may not be blank, but TeX will consider it as a standard letter, not as a space.