# Issue with xcookybooky compiling example

Tags: xcookybooky

I just found the package `xcookybooky` to compile a cook book. After installation of the packages (`xcookybooky`, `cookingsymbols`, `ifsym` and `emerald` fonts), i expected to compile the `example.tex` who stay in the [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcookybooky).

I run the code with pdfLaTeX and LaTeX gives me this error :
`Font U/cookingsymbols/m/n/14.5=cookingsymbols at 14.5pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{recipe}`

I just comment the `[ngerman]` option of the `babel` package and the corresponding `\begin{otherlanguage}...\end{otherlanguage}` in the example.tex. But i'm not sure it was a problem for the font size of a symbol...

How can i fix that problem and hope to compile my own recipe book (: ?

Comment: The metric files should be created automatically when you use the package for the first time - however, you can also create them manually from the file `cookingsymbols.mf` using Metafont (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142592/metafont-or-alternative-ways-to-get-your-own-scripts-within-latex the `mf` command at the end of the answer for an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Marijin , i could understand where was the problem. The new installed fonts were not totally available.

I solved the problem by installing :

```
 sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
 sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
 sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german
```

For some reason, the package needs some unicode available only in `ngerman` option of babel package. So i had to install and reset this option in the preamble.

Thanks for the help, problem solved !